# possible to use play framework with pivot4j/jpivot?

Tags: playframework

We are planning to use pivot4j/jpivot in web app, but looks like pivot4j/jpivot is based on JSP tag while play doesn't support JSP, so play doesn't support pivot4j/jpivot, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

[Pivot4J](http://www.pivot4j.org) core does not depend on JSP, and is specifically designed to allow building arbitary UI frontends on top of it.

Pivot4J Analytics, on the other hand, depends on JSF/PrimeFaces and is far less flexible as it is a complete application rather than a library.

If you need any assistance in integrating Pivot4J with Play framework, please visit our [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pivot4j-list), and I'll be happy to help.

Hope this helps!